# IndexError: list index out of range Why can't I acsess two-dimensional array？

Tags: python, django

I cannot acsess the two-dimensional array.
I wrote

```
book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows):
    row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    area_row = row[0] or area_row
    row[0] = area_row
    if len(fourrows) == 5:
       fourrows=[]
    fourrows.append(row)
    fourrows_transpose=list(map(list, zip(*fourrows)))
    val3 = sheet3.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=9)
    user3 = User.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3).first()
    if user3:
       area = Area.objects.filter(name="America").first()
       pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="prefecture", area=user3.area)
       city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref)
       price_u1000 = Price.upper1000.objects.get(city=city)
       price_500_1000 = Price.from500to1000.objects.get(city=city)
       price_u500 = Price.under500.objects.get(city=city)

       pref.name = "NY"
       pref.save()

         for i in range(2,len(fourrows_transpose)):
             city.name = fourrows_transpose[i][1]
             city.save()
             print(fourrows_transpose[i][1])

             price_u1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][2]
             price_u1000.save()
             print(fourrows_transpose[i][2])

             price_500_1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][3]
             price_500_1000.save()
             print(fourrows_transpose[i][3])

             price_u500.name = fourrows_transpose[i][4]
             price_u500.save()
             print(fourrows_transpose[i][4])
```

In print(fourrows_transpose),it is shown

```
[['America', 'America', 'America', 'America', 'America'], ['', '', 'u1000', '500～1000', 'd500'], ['NY', 'City A', '×', '×', '×'], ['NY', 'City B', '×', '×', '×'], ['NY', 'City C', '×', '×', '×'], ['NY', 'City D', '×', '×', '×'], ['NY', 'City E', '×', '×', '×']]
```

Now error happens:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Traceback says:

```
city.name = fourrows_transpose[i][1]
```

is wrong. but I think `fourrows_transpose` is two-dimensional arrays,so I really cannot understand why I cannot access `fourrows_transpose[2][1]`. What is wrong? How should  I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try simple construction:

```
     for transpose in fourrows_transpose[2:]:
         city.name = transpose[1]
         city.save()
         print(transpose[1])

         price_u1000.name = transpose[2]
         price_u1000.save()
         print(transpose[2])

         price_500_1000.name = transpose[3]
         price_500_1000.save()
         print(transpose[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2,len(fourrows_transpose)):
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # ...
```

Assuming you have an array `arrayNumbers = {0,1,2,3,4}`

That array has 5 elements (=`len(arrayNumbers)`), but max. index is 4. In this case your loop would say: "Run from index 2 up to index 5." So the last run of your loop tries to access `arrayNumbers[5]` which does not exist.

So, you need to decrement your max. index value in your `for` loop by 1.

Comment: `range(2,len(fourrows_transpose))` in this case == `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Why -1 ? Anyhow range(1,5) = [1, 2, 3, 4] , it includes 1st index and excluding last (i.e. here 5)

Comment: "decrement your **max.** index value" - not you min. value

Answer (score 0):

```
Actual problem is here.
city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref) 
price_u1000 = Price.upper1000.objects.get(city=city) 
price_500_1000 =Price.from500to1000.objects.get(city=city) 
price_u500 = Price.under500.objects.get(city=city)
here you will have to filter data as you done like

area = Area.objects.filter(name="America").first()
```

Answer (score -1):

because in your code you have:

```
for i in range(2,len(fourrows_transpose)):
```

try:

```
for i in range(0,len(fourrows_transpose)-1):
```

Comment: Why -1 ? Anyhow range(1,4), it includes 1st index and excluding last (i.e. here 4)

Comment: my bad. from zero

Comment: Even though you are accessing from 0th index, range(0,len(list)) always takes 0,1,2,... list(len)-1 th index. (i.e. always exclude list[len(list)]) in range method.